# What is a point-of-load converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Can you please give me a definition, or at least a more specific context, of the term "point-of-load" converter/regulator? I have seen around explanations on related products or applications but no real definition. Most important for me is, why do we need this extra term, instead of just saying DC-DC converter? Isn't that the same?

Thank you for your attention,
Leonidas

Comment: Just saying "dc/dc" doesn't tell where it is going to be placed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm using 5V as an example below.

You can either "bus around" a big 5V power system to various loads and devices using heavy duty copper wires or PCB tracks or, you can have a bunch of smaller regulators individually close to their respective loads/devices.

The latter is called a point of load converter. "Converter" is just another name for a voltage regulator and, quite often, they are switching converters. You still have to "bus around" power to the converters but this is done at a much higher voltage (maybe 48 volts) and therefore the overall current drawn in this new bus is much lower and wires/tracks can be thinner.

The other advantage is that the 48V can be quite ripply/flaky but the localized converters will turn this into a much cleaner 5V for their immediate loads.

Because lower currents now flow around the bus, emissions (EMI) are usually smaller and susceptibility (again to do with EMC) is usually improved.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Andy. One more question though. You say that a 48V "bussed" current may be ripply/flaky. Why is that? Because of the different loads?

Comment: I'm saying that if the 48V was a little under regulated and contained ripples and load transients it wouldn't matter too much because the local regulators would iron that out.